# Xamarin Android app splash screen not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I am learning the android development in visual studio 2022.

when i creating a splash screen, it splashes default Xamarin logo. can some have a look at the code and guide me with resolving this issue.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3BKe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHIuV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV6O6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMaA7.png)

i have tried lots of combinations available online like adding image path in splash.cs. it works but it was not full screen image, rather a very small image.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as images. Code and exceptions should always be provided in text form. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may want to have a look at the official Android documentation, because there are some limitations regarding what's possible with splash screens on newer versions of Android: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: What version of Android do you use? You can try changing the size of the image.